# Ошибка в приложении

Tags: android

[image]

Запускаю приложение, но, к сожалению, выводится лишь форма с именем проекта, а я отправил get запрос, что не так?

Всё сделал правильно, скачал библиотеку, прописал в Gradle, но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что вы отправляли запрос? в коде, что по ссылке нету отправки запроса.

Comment:  AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler () { 

Нашел такой код, но не знаю как передать данные в строку

Comment: @Frehir, если не знаете предметную область - выучите ее сначала. Не хотите учить - закажите работу на фрилансе. За вас вашу работу никто не собирается сделать.

Comment: Я просто хочу узнать, как отправить get запрос и всё, пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: Да, никто!

Answer (score 1):

Среда вам говорит о том, что метод get не используется! Вызовите его в onCreate()